# Why Am I Getting a Negative Number from this code in processing?

Tags: processing

Please help, I cannot figure out why this code prints a negative number instead of a value from 0 - 255.

```java
void setup() {
    size(1024, 1024);
    background(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255));
    println(get(1,1));
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is describe [here](https://processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html) in Processing documentation:

> From a technical standpoint, colors are 32 bits of information ordered
> as AAAAAAAARRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBB where the A's contain the alpha
> value, the R's are the red value, G's are green, and B's are blue.
> Each component is 8 bits (a number between 0 and 255). These values
> can be manipulated with [bit shifting](https://processing.org/reference/rightshift.html).

The `color` type is secretly an `int`. In second reference [bit shifting](https://processing.org/reference/rightshift.html) is descibed how you can use this value to extract alpha, red, green and blue:

```
// Using "right shift" as a faster technique than red(), green(), and blue()
color argb = color(204, 204, 51, 255);
int a = (argb >> 24) & 0xFF; 
int r = (argb >> 16) & 0xFF;  // Faster way of getting red(argb)
int g = (argb >> 8) & 0xFF;   // Faster way of getting green(argb)
int b = argb & 0xFF;          // Faster way of getting blue(argb)
fill(r, g, b, a);
rect(30, 20, 55, 55);
```

- `>>` - shift bits to right, i.e. cut last 24bits
- `& 0xFF` - get only last 8 bits

and according to the authors, this is a faster method than `red()`, `green()`, and `blue()` functions.

If you want to compute this value by yourself, I tried to recreate the calculation:

```
int a = 255;
int r = 204;
int g = 204;
int b = 51;
int res = ((-128*int(a/128)+int(a%128))<<24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
```

- `((-128*int(a/128)+int(a%128))<<24)` - Alpha is between [0;255]. In their solution alpha is tranform between [-128;127] with [overflow of range](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/7412/signed-integer-overflow), i.e. 126=>126, 127=>127, 128=>-128, 129=>-127 and so on 255=>-1

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this are best answered by looking at [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/get_.html).

The `get()` function returns a `color` type. Behind the scenes, `color` is represented by an `int` value, which is what you're seeing when you print it. You usually don't need to worry about this `int` value, and you can just use the `color` type directly, for example by passing into the `fill()` function.

But if you want the RGB values from a `color` value, you can use the `red()`, `green()`, and `blue()` functions.